# Optimal way to extract files from ZIP dependency needed by build

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

Our build requires a couple of special dependencies stored in a Maven repository, that are not simple Java libraries, such as Zip files containing JavaScript/CSS components to be included in the webapp, or command line build tools to perform various tasks. In some cases for this build I only need a small part of an otherwise large zip archive.

The initial solution was to just use a "type:Copy" task, but I am finding for larger archives several seconds get added to the "configuration" stage, and several seconds again to execution for the up-to-date check after the initial build did all the work.

Does Gradle have a better means to deal with such dependencies? I am not sure what the configuration difficulty is at all, and I am guessing the up-to-date check goes through the file tree and checks each file, which I don't really need, neither the zip or the output directory get modified by the build. And Gradle should already know if it just happened to get an updated dependency from the repo or not?

```
ext {
    barVersion = "1.0.9"
    barBaseDir = "${buildDeps}/bar"
    //Would ideally like to not deal with this, and extract "*.zip/*/" directly to
    //"${buildDeps}/bar"
    barDir = "${buildDeps}/bar/bar-${barVersion}"
}
configurations {
    special
}
dependencies {
    special "com.mycorp.foo:bar:${barVersion}@zip"
}
task extractBar(type:Copy) {
    destinationDir = file barBaseDir
    from zipTree(configurations.special.fileCollection{dep -> dep.name == 'bar'}.singleFile)
    //Some times only need a small part for the actual build. The full package may either not be
    //required for this build, or only at runtime on the end server
    include "*/js/**/*"
    include "*/sass/**/*"
    include "*/schemas/**/*"
}
```

Comment: Rather not, it's done well.